# The top and the bottom end of movies recorded by Agora On-premise recording SDK are cut off

Tags: agora.io

I would like to develop a recorder of video streamed by portrait screen of smartphone users using Agora On-premise SDK.

However, the top and the bottom end of recorded movies are cut off because options of aspect ratio do not include portraits.

I implement this by rewrite Agora Restful Recording Nodejs Sample.
https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Recording

Can I take any option to resolve this problem?
Or, can I rewrite the SDK file to resolve this problem?
Or, video stream has already been cut off since the server received it?

The script is as follows.

```js
const { RtcTokenBuilder, RtcRole } = require("agora-access-token")
const AgoraRecordingSDK = require("./AgoraRecordSdk");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

require('dotenv').config();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}

const publisher_uid = "*********"
const channelName = "*********"

startRecording(channelName,publisher_uid)

function startRecording(channelName,publisher_uid) {
    let rec = new AgoraRecordingSDK();
    let layout = {
        "canvasWidth": 480,
        "canvasHeight": 480,
        "backgroundColor": "#eeeeee",
        "regions": []
    }
    rec.setMixLayout(layout);
    rec.on("joinchannel", function (channel, uid) {
        console.log(`channel joined ${channel} ${uid}`);
    });
    rec.on("error", function (err, stat) {
        console.log(`err ${err} ${stat}`);
    });
    rec.on("recordingStats", function(stats) {
        console.log(`recording stats ${JSON.stringify(stats)}`)
    })
    rec.on("userleave", function(uid) {
        console.log(`userleave ${uid}`);
        if(String(uid) == String(publisher_uid)){
            rec.leaveChannel();
        }
    });
    rec.on("userjoin", function (uid) {
        //rearrange layout when new user joins
        console.log(`userjoin ${uid}`);
        if(String(uid) == String(publisher_uid)){
            let region = {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 480,
                "height": 480,
                "zOrder": 1,
                "alpha": 1,
                "uid": uid
            }
            layout.regions.push(region)
            rec.setMixLayout(layout);
        }
    });
    let storageDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "./output/"+channelName);
    const token = function () {
        const role = RtcRole.SUBSCRIBER
        const expirationTimeInSeconds = 60 * 150
        const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
        const privilegeExpiredTs = currentTimestamp + expirationTimeInSeconds
        const token = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(process.env.APP_ID, process.env.APP_CERTIFICATE, channelName, Number(process.env.UID), role, privilegeExpiredTs)
        return token
    }
    fs.mkdir(storageDir, {recursive: true}, async (err) => {
        console.log("err:"+err)
        //join channel
        await rec.joinChannel(token(), channelName, Number(process.env.UID), process.env.APP_ID, storageDir);
    })
    return rec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the top and bottom to be cut off, you can just change the render mode to be fit instead of hidden. That will introduce black bars to the side instead of cutting off the video. You will need to add the render mode inside the region object like this:

```
let region = {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "width": 480,
  "height": 480,
  "zOrder": 1,
  "alpha": 1,
  "renderMode": 1,
  "uid": uid
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried that with the following code, but the recorded video is all black and shows nothing.

let region = {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "width": 480,
  "height": 480,
  "zOrder": 1,
  "alpha": 1,
  "renderMode": 1,
  "uid": uid
}

I also tried that with the following code, but the results were the same.

let region = {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "width": 1280,
  "height": 720,
  "zOrder": 1,
  "alpha": 1,
  "renderMode": 1,
  "uid": uid
}

If you have any solutions, please let me know.

Comment: Hey. Just so I understand, you were having the video recorded but had the sides cut off when not adding renderMode. As soon as you added renderMode, the recording turns black. Is that right?

Comment: The latter is right but the former is not right.
When not adding renderMode, had the sides do not cut off and just cut off upside and downside.  As soon as I added renderMode, the recording turns black.

Comment: When you say "the sides", do you mean the sides including the top and bottom? If so, then what you are saying is correct. Sorry.

Comment: Hey @kokucoco. That looks like a bug to me. Can you please file a ticket at https://agora-ticket.agora.io/?

Comment: I contacted a support staff of agora and the problem is solved.  Thank you.